# Is this contradiction faulty?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Firstly, we have a set $S=\{x \in [a,b] \mid f(x) \le 0 \}$, with its supremum being $c$. Now, we want to disprove that $f(c)<0$, and the writer begins by stating that $\forall x \in (c-\delta_2,c+\delta_2) f(x)<0$. Next, he states that $c+\delta_2 \in S$, which I find perplexing as $c+\delta_2 \notin [a,b] \because c \geq x \forall x \in S$. Sorry if I'm missing something really simple out, but whatever it is it doesn't seem clear to me.

(Note: Continuity of $f$ is assumed, and $f(c)<0$ was first supposed.)

P.S. A similar question of mine was posted yesterday and the reason I did not include this within it was because I felt it would make my previous question too heavy.

Comment: $f(c)<0$ can be true. For example $[a,b]=[-2,-1]$ and $f(x)=x$. Then $S=[-2,-1]$, with $c=-1$ and $f(c)=f(-1)=-1$. Something is unclear in your post.

Comment: $f(c)$ can be anything by the information given. If you assume it, how can you go and disprove it??? You can not bring it to a contradiction, because the rest says nothing about whether $f(c)<0$ or $f(c)=0$.

Comment: @Stef We want to disprove that $f(c)<0$ so we first suppose that $f(c)<0$ and go on to derive a contradiction .

Comment: That is what I say and my example above. With the rest of the information you cannot derive a contradiction. Did you read my example? Can you derive a contradiction there?

Comment: My question is regarding the 5th last step of proving Bolzano's Theorem from here: http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/IntValueTheorem13.htm.  I tried to add in all the relevant and necessary information from the link to my question, and with the ciunterexample you have provided it would seem that the proof is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $c + \delta_2$ may not be in $S$. Therefore this is a wrong step in the proof.

An simple counter example would be $f(x) = x$ on $[a,b]=[-1,0]$. Then $c=0$ and for all $\delta>0$ we have $(-\delta,\delta)$ is not a subset of $[-1,0]$.

Comment: That's what I thought as well but the text seems to be stating otherwise : http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/IntValueTheorem13.htm (the 5th last step in proving Bolazno's Theorem).

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú It seems to be a very confused person who wrote that website. For example, if $S$ is all the values where $f$ is $\le 0$ the person makes a case distinction for values where $f$ is $>0$. Perhaps you can find better proofs in a book. Or on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at one of the proofs that were discussed pn Math.SE after I realized some of the flawed arguments.